# Unable to unpack pymysql query result to variables

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a script that collects data from a database. I wanted to refine the script a bit, but ran into trouble.

I'm running a query that I know will ALWAYS return only one row with 3 values in it. I want to unpack those values into separate variables, but only the last seems to actually have some sort of value.

Here's my code:

```
import pymysql

cnx = pymysql.connect(host=dbHost, database=dbName, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass)
query = "select id_parameter,unit,shortname from t_list_metpara where shortname='TT'"

with cnx.cursor() as cursor1:
    cursor1.execute(query)
    row = cursor1.fetchone()

cnx.close()
id_parameter, unit, shortname = row[:3]

print(row)
print(id_parameter, unit, shortname)
print([type(v) for v in [id_parameter, unit, shortname]])
print([row[v] for v in [0, 1, 2]])
```

and the result:

```
(1, 'Â°C\r', 'tt')
 tt
[<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
[1, 'Â°C\r', 'tt']
```

Can anyone explain to my why Python (or the pymysql package) behaves this way, and what I can do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pymysql, or even Python itself, and there is nothing wrong with your variables.

`\r` means a carriage return character. If you print something followed by a `\r`, the cursor position will return to the start of the line; the next character will begin from the start of that line. If you printed each of `id_paramter`, `unit` and `shortname` separately, you would see all the data.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that... Thanks anyway!